# How to list non-empty cells when the adjacent cell is empty in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Hellooo I need help ;'(**

How do you make the result such that the all values in the column beside the adjacent empty column be listed out like this?

[I dont mind if its coded inside the app script too. I just need a guide to know how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpiZd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
=Filter(B2:B,(C2:C="")*(B2:B<>""))
```

Filter function is one of several spill ranges that can do this.